# prevent chrome from asking to confirm

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

Sometimes I get this message from Chrome:

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
>   properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you
>   will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press the
>   reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>   ERR_CACHE_MISS

Is there a way to prevent this message?

I tried using AJAX with the following:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false;
        });    
    });
});
</script>
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Yes. Use ajax to submit forms, instead of regular submit-buttons/posting content to other pages.

Comment: Or use POST-Redirect-GET.

Comment: I've looked at the post redirect get posts on overflow and honestly don't understand them.  Is there a simple explanation or source you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy, stackoverflow really lead me astray on this one.  The problem is solved by placing any of the following commands at the beginning of the control file:

```
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','private');
session_cache_limiter(false);
```

tried each of these separately and they all solved the problem